# Handling Linux Network Connectivity in Java/C++?

Tags: java, c++, linux, networking, network-programming

I am working on a program to handle connections in Ubuntu. I am currently doing it in Java, but aim to do it in C++ too. 
Essentially, atm I am just running system commands through Java:

```
proc.exec("ifconfig wlan0 down"); etc.
```

I get some printout saying it is 'deconfiguring interfaces' and 'fail' is printed out.
First off, does anybody know why?

Secondly, can anyone think of a better way of doing this? In the end, I want the program to have the computer run an Ad Hoc network, drop the connection and connect to another network, and pick up the Ad Hoc again when it is done with the other network.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not really giving us a lot of info to work with. Are you running the program with root priviledges?

Comment: I think the fail issue was due to me not writing sudo -i before the commands. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can try to interface [NetworkManager](http://live.gnome.org/NetworkManager), which uses [D-Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) as its interface, and there exists [Java implementations of the protocol](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DBusBindings).

Comment: Thanks, just downloaded and looks like it should do what Im after. Felt a bit inefficient to have a program run through terminal commands, a lot harder to detect or handle errors!